# Can I run a Virtual PC and VMWARE Guest as the same time on the same machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualization

I want to setup a couple a virtual machines and want to know if I can have two (or more) hypervisors running at the same time on the same machine?  Note:  The host machine is Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: stackoverflow is not the right site for this question. It should have been asked on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to run different VM software packages that both use hardware virtualization.  It might be possible to run both at the same time if you have hardware virtualization disabled on both.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't think so wanted to know for sure.